# How to use Oracle Wallet in PortalContext when connecting to Oracle BRM pcm_client?

Tags: oracle

I have a Java code that connects to Oracle BRM using portal context. Connection using Infranet.properties with entry below is OK.

`infranet.connection=pcp://<username>:<password>@<hostname>:11960/service/pcm_client`

Java code :

```
PortalContext portalContext = null;
try {
    log.debug("Connecting PortalContext to BRM");
    portalContext = new PortalContext(infranetProperties.getInfranetProperties());
    portalContext.connect();
    log.debug("PortalContext connected");
} catch (EBufException|BRMException e) {
    log.error("BRM Error : {}", e.toString());
    .
    .
}
```

However, instead of using connection string, I would like to use Oracle Wallet to hide the login credentials. Is it possible?

I tried to create an entry in the wallet, containing the connection string

```
C:\opt\portal\BRM\wallet\client\devb>mkstore -wrl . -listCredential
Oracle Secret Store Tool Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 2004, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Enter wallet password:
List credential (index: connect_string username)
3: ---------------
2: <hostname>:11960/service/pcm_client root.0.0.0.1
1: ---------------
```

with infranet.properties this entry in tnsnames.ora

`infranet.connection=pcp://root.0.0.0.1@<hostname>:11960/service/pcm_client`

But I got ERR_BAD_LOGIN_RESULT error

```
BRM Error : ERR_BAD_LOGIN_RESULT
java.lang.String:0: ErrBuf Fields:
Error=ERR_BAD_LOGIN_RESULT    Loc=PCP
Field=PIN_FLD_RESULT    Rec=0    reserved=0
Facility=0    MessageID=0    Time=7:44 AM    Version=0    Reserved2=0
Args=<none>
Nested Error:
<none>
```

infranet.log.file contains this :

> Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0161 AM ( 1700696669162 )
> T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog parseConnectString
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> parsing
> pcp://root.0.0.0.1@hostname:XXXX@hostname:11960/service/pcm_client
> Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0229 AM ( 1700696669230 )
> T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog parseConnectString
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> filled in: 0 PIN_FLD_POID                      POID [0] 0.0.0.1
> /service/pcm_client 1 0 0 PIN_FLD_LOGIN                      STR [0]
> "root.0.0.0.1" 0 PIN_FLD_CM_PTRS                  ARRAY [0] allocated
> 1, used 1 1     PIN_FLD_CM_PTR                 STR [0] "ip hostname
> 11960"
>
> Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0232 AM ( 1700696669232 )
> T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] Inside connect() API PcmTimeoutInMsecs=0 Debug
> 11/23/23 7:44:29:0233 AM ( 1700696669233 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3
> JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] loginFlist supplied Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0233 AM ( 1700696669233 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] FLIST Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0234 AM (
> 1700696669234 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> 0 PIN_FLD_POID                      POID [0] 0.0.0.1
> /service/pcm_client 1 0 0 PIN_FLD_LOGIN                      STR [0]
> "root.0.0.0.1" 0 PIN_FLD_TIMEOUT_IN_MS              INT [0] 0 0
> PIN_FLD_CM_PTRS                  ARRAY [0] allocated 1, used 1 1
> PIN_FLD_CM_PTR                 STR [0] "ip hostname 11960" 0
> PIN_FLD_TYPE                      ENUM [0] 1
>
> Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0234 AM ( 1700696669234 )
> T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] PCPContext Hashcode: 78466973 Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0236 AM ( 1700696669236 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] Creating new PCPClientOperation Hashcode:
> 1562929256 Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0238 AM ( 1700696669238 )
> T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] PCPConnection :155995279 Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0238 AM ( 1700696669239 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] Inside PCPConnection() PcmTimeoutInMsecs=0
> Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0239 AM ( 1700696669239 )
> T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] PCPConnection : reconnect Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0239 AM ( 1700696669239 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD ip hostname 11960 Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0240 AM ( 1700696669240 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD connecting to host "hostname" at port
> "11960" Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0240 AM ( 1700696669240 )
> T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD Trying to acquire SSLContext. Debug
> 11/23/23 7:44:29:0242 AM ( 1700696669242 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3
> JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] Reading WalletLoc from absolute
> path:/opt/portal/BRM/wallet/client/devb\cwallet.sso Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0307 AM ( 1700696669307 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] Using algorithm:SunX509 Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0309 AM ( 1700696669309 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD SSLContext acquired. Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0384 AM ( 1700696669384 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD Created SSL socket . Trying Handshake.
> Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0590 AM ( 1700696669590 )
> T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD Handshake Done.Negotiated protocol :
> TLSv1.2 Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0590 AM ( 1700696669590 )
> T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD Connected to host: hostname Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0594 AM ( 1700696669594 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD connected Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0594 AM (
> 1700696669594 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD set socket timeout to 0milli-seconds Debug
> 11/23/23 7:44:29:0594 AM ( 1700696669594 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3
> JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] PCPConnection : login Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0595 AM ( 1700696669595 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] PCPContext execute: Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0595 AM ( 1700696669595 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD op=9 opflags=0 Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0595
> AM ( 1700696669595 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD request flist
>
> Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0595 AM ( 1700696669595 )
> T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] FLIST Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0595 AM (
> 1700696669595 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> 0 PIN_FLD_LOGIN                      STR [0] "root.0.0.0.1" 0
> PIN_FLD_POID                      POID [0] 0.0.0.1 /service/pcm_client
> 1 0 0 PIN_FLD_TIMEOUT_IN_MS              INT [0] 0 0 PIN_FLD_CM_PTRS
> ARRAY [0] allocated 1, used 1 1     PIN_FLD_CM_PTR                 STR
> [0] "ip hostname 11960" 0 PIN_FLD_TYPE                      ENUM [0] 1
>
> Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0595 AM ( 1700696669595 )
> T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] PCPContext execute: Received normal opcode
> Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0596 AM ( 1700696669596 )
> T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] PCPConnection :onImplicit : State = 0 Debug
> 11/23/23 7:44:29:0596 AM ( 1700696669596 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3
> JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD implicit trans of type ro Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0596 AM ( 1700696669596 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] PCPContext send: Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0596
> AM ( 1700696669596 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD about to send req Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0596 AM ( 1700696669596 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] PCPContext resend: Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0596
> AM ( 1700696669596 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] PCPContext resend: Starting write Debug
> 11/23/23 7:44:29:0597 AM ( 1700696669597 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3
> JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD write WH:
> chunk=0,sfs=0x104,len=0xc8,op=9,opf=0x0,pcpf=0x1
> udb=1,uid=1,opdb=1,opid=1 Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0618 AM ( 1700696669618 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD PROBE ok interval 21 ms Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0618 AM ( 1700696669618 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD sending Beg_(len = 0x108) Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0618 AM ( 1700696669618 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD sending *End Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0619
> AM ( 1700696669619 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] PCPContext resend: Finished resend
> successfully Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0619 AM ( 1700696669619 )
> T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD sent req Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0619 AM (
> 1700696669619 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD op=9 opflags=0 Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0619
> AM ( 1700696669619 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD about to receive resp Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0619 AM ( 1700696669619 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] PCPContext receive: Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0619 AM ( 1700696669619 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD reading beg*: (Req: 0x40) Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0669 AM ( 1700696669669 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD available: 0x40 Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0669 AM ( 1700696669669 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD reading *end Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0669
> AM ( 1700696669669 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD read WH:
> chunk=0,sfs=0x0,len=0xb8,op=9,opf=0x0,pcpf=0x2
> udb=1,uid=1,opdb=1,opid=1 Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0669 AM ( 1700696669669 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD reading beg*: (Req: 0xb8) Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0669 AM ( 1700696669669 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD available: 0xb8 Debug 11/23/23
> 7:44:29:0669 AM ( 1700696669669 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD reading _end Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0670
> AM ( 1700696669671 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD received resp Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0671
> AM ( 1700696669671 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] PCPContext receive: Finished receive
> successfully Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0671 AM ( 1700696669671 )
> T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD response flist
>
> Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0671 AM ( 1700696669671 )
> T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] FLIST Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0671 AM (
> 1700696669671 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> 0 PIN_FLD_OP_CORRELATION_ID          STR [0]
> "2:hostname:cm:25014:-146647296:9:1700696662:1::::" 0 PIN_FLD_RESULT
> ENUM [0] 2 0 PIN_FLD_POID                      POID [0] 0.0.0.1
> /service/pcm_client 1 0 0 PIN_FLD_TYPE                      ENUM [0] 1
>
> Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0671 AM ( 1700696669671 )
> T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] Ignore onOpDone in case of bad login response
> or transactional flow Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0671 AM ( 1700696669671 )
> T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DDD completed op Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0674
> AM ( 1700696669674 )  T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog 
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] No more cm ptrs, setting login flag value to
> :false Debug 11/23/23 7:44:29:0682 AM ( 1700696669682 )
> T:http-nio-8080-exec-3 JavaLog getSocketChannel
> 2:LPSMYS20L0137:UnknownProgramName:0:http-nio-8080-exec-3:0:1700696669:0::::
> Context, Connection or Socket Channel is null for PortalContext :
> 106140890

Looks like PortalContext is still looking for infranet.connection